# Where to change "Joomla is free software."

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I'm changing some signs of Joomla from the admin panel, but I have problems with some of them.
For example, I cannot find where to change "Joomla is free software." I searched most of the files, but I didn't find that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, i think you shouldn't eliminate those signs, as you are asked about it; to not remove them.

But for that specific one, as it's not about removing joomla's license, you can go to the following address:

~administrator\templates(template-name)\language\en-GB\en-GB.tpl_isis.ini

search for something like this:
TPL_ISIS_ISFREESOFTWARE

and also remember to change it in your own language (if it's not English)

Comment: @scotperss you should take a look at its terms and conditions :)

Comment: Don't alter the language file directly, because it might be overwritten on an update. Use the [language override feature](http://docs.joomla.org/Help31:Extensions_Language_Manager_Overrides) instead.

Comment: @nibra that feature isn't available in Joomla 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Some of these "brandings" will be in the template index.php file.